# Change text onclick div with animation using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have these `divs` filled with numbers. I was trying to change these numbers based on the menu clicked, which is working neatly. But I want this text change along with some animation like here

http://bfintal.github.io/Counter-Up/demo/demo.html.

My basic code is explained here
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwaran/38ep0va6/1/).

So when I click on any of those 16 buttons, the values inside the grid should counterup and change. The problem is that it doesn't animate but shows the result immediately

Hope I made it clear

JS:

```
$('.one').click(function() {
  $('#aries').show( "slow" ).html('60');
  $('#taurus').show( "slow" ).html('20');
  $('#gemini').show( "slow" ).html('30');
  $('#cancer').show( "slow" ).html('10');
  $('#leo').show( "slow" ).html('50');
  $('#virgo').show( "slow" ).html('40');
  $('#libra').show( "slow" ).html('90');
  $('#scorpio').show( "slow" ).html('70');
  $('#sagittarius').show( "slow" ).html('33');
  $('#capricorn').show( "slow" ).html('98');
  $('#aquarius').show( "slow" ).html('56');
  $('#pisces').show( "slow" ).html('88');
});

$('.two').click(function() {
  $('#aries').show( "slow" ).html('60');
  $('#taurus').show( "slow" ).html('60');
  $('#gemini').show( "slow" ).html('60');
  $('#cancer').show( "slow" ).html('60');
  $('#leo').show( "slow" ).html('60');
  $('#virgo').show( "slow" ).html('60');
  $('#libra').show( "slow" ).html('60');
  $('#scorpio').show( "slow" ).html('60');
  $('#sagittarius').show( "slow" ).html('60');
  $('#capricorn').show( "slow" ).html('60');
  $('#aquarius').show( "slow" ).html('60');
  $('#pisces').show( "slow" ).html('60');
});


$('.three').click(function() {
   $('#aries').show( "slow" ).html('65');
  $('#taurus').show( "slow" ).html('60');
  $('#gemini').show( "slow" ).html('84');
  $('#cancer').show( "slow" ).html('74');
  $('#leo').show( "slow" ).html('21');
  $('#virgo').show( "slow" ).html('77');
  $('#libra').show( "slow" ).html('44');
  $('#scorpio').show( "slow" ).html('78');
  $('#sagittarius').show( "slow" ).html('65');
  $('#capricorn').show( "slow" ).html('36');
  $('#aquarius').show( "slow" ).html('29');
  $('#pisces').show( "slow" ).html('81');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
            <div id="aries" class="button turquoise">12</div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer">
            <div id="taurus" class="button peterriver">11</div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer">
            <div id="gemini" class="button emerland">7</div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer">
            <div id="cancer" class="button amethyst">8</div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer">
            <div id="leo" class="button wisteria">9</div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer">
            <div id="virgo" class="button sunflower">4</div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer">
            <div id="libra" class="button wetasphalt">5</div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer">
            <div id="scorpio" class="button belizehole">6</div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer">
            <div id="sagittarius" class="button nephritis">1</div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer">
            <div id="capricorn" class="button alizarin">2</div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer">
            <div id="aquarius" class="button greensea">3</div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer">
            <div id="pisces" class="button orange">10</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please let me know what you did not understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link your provided as demo is not actually animation, it's just re-rendering the values.

I maded some kind of counter for your case. See: [Updated Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38ep0va6/12/)

This will work for you.
In [Updated Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38ep0va6/12/) You can change some lines of code, for different behavior:

1. If you want to increase the speed of counting values. You can change:

   `line 56`: `smoothCount(div, start, end, 2);`

to :

```
`smoothCount(div, start, end, YOUR_VALUE);`
```

Replace "YOUR_VALUE" with an int (miliseconds).
Higher values will decrease the speed.

Comment: Woah. This is exactly what I wanted. But would you please help me on how to make the code more efficient. I understand that I would have to write onclick event for all 16 buttons. Is there any alternative to that?

Comment: How to refactor this code is very common question. It depends on: 1. from where this values come? May be database, XML, or you will write it hardcoded inside the code? 2.What is the structure of the application you working on? I think you need to ask another question if you can organize this information. Or you need more knowledge to do it without asking at all, cuz this is common question at all.

Comment: The values are hardcoded. This is the only thing thats gonna be on the webpage.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Maybe I've misled you. In case this values are hardcoded, and the content of the site is not very big, You do not need refactoring. May be is possible to do little, but I do not know how this should be done.